# Code for printing headers and corresponding values of tsv file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I would like to know how to extract the corresponding header for a value that matches a regex expression in bash. I have the following table as a tsv:

[image]

I would like to match only the values that are not "-" and print the header corresponding to it as in the following:

isoniazid (ahpC_p.Asp73His)

What would be a simple code for this in bash?

Comment: Please include sample text (not image) and expected output with your attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `awk` script would output what you need:

```
 awk 'NR == 1 { split($0, T); next }
              { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
                  if ($i != "-") {
                    printf "%s (%s)\n", T[i], $i }
                  }
              }' your_file_name
```

Just replace `your_file_name` with whatever TSV file you want to parse.

Comment: `NR==1{split($0,t); next}` is enough

Comment: @karakfa, you are right. It's more elegant to use split. I updated the code above.

Comment: For some reason when I try working this into a WDL script it gives this error: `Error: Invalid WDL: Failed to read task definition at line 28 column 6 (reason 1 of 1): Cannot mix leading whitespace characters in command: [" ", "\t"]`